# Javascript: Write Console.debug() output to browser?

Tags: javascript, json, loops

I need to be able to take any JSON data and print the key/value pairs.

(something similar to print_r() in PHP)

Is this even possible with javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can process a surprising amount of info through alert, and you can also use it for debugging.

Here is a print_r [equivalent for javascript](http://www.brandnewbox.co.uk/articles/details/a_print_r_equivalent_for_javascript/) also.

```
function print_r(theObj){
  if(theObj.constructor == Array ||
     theObj.constructor == Object){
    document.write("<ul>")
    for(var p in theObj){
      if(theObj[p].constructor == Array||
         theObj[p].constructor == Object){
document.write("<li>["+p+"] => "+typeof(theObj)+"</li>");
        document.write("<ul>")
        print_r(theObj[p]);
        document.write("</ul>")
      } else {
document.write("<li>["+p+"] => "+theObj[p]+"</li>");
      }
    }
    document.write("</ul>")
  }
}
```

good luck with your project!

Comment: argh i just had about half of that written.

Answer (score 13):

I usually just quickly create a log function that allows you change the logging method.  Write enablers/disablers or comment out to choose the options.

```
function log(msg){
  if (window.console && console.log) {
    console.log(msg); //for firebug
  }
  document.write(msg); //write to screen
  $("#logBox").append(msg); //log to container
}
```

Update: Info on Firebug's [Console API](http://getfirebug.com/logging)

Update: Added check for non firebug browsers.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to get a JSON parsing library like [JSON2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) for being able to "stringify" your objects, then you can simply:

```
var myString = JSON.stringify(myObject);
```

`myString` will now contain a string representation of `myObject`.

But if it's for debugging purposes I would recommend you to get a JavaScript debugger, like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), you get a lot of useful functions in the [Console API](http://getfirebug.com/console.html).

Answer (score 1):

can you simply use the following:

```
 document.write('<h2>Your Text and or HTML here.</h2>');
```

Answer (score 0):

FireBug is a great tool!  Indispensable!  I found it eliminates the need to write debug data into my pages and I can view JSON all day long.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to be able to take any JSON
>   data and print the key/value pairs.

Well then print the JSON data. JSON is a notation, not an object. If you have JSON data, you already have all you need. If you want it to be a little more fancy, you might want to add a linebreak after every `"\s*,`.

If you want to deconstruct an object, it's not possible unless you're using JavaScript, as ECMAScript can't create cyclic references in a single object literal. If this is JavaScript-only, then you can use `uneval(object)`, which will make use of sharp variables. (eg. `({x:#1={y:#1#}})`).