# Simple cross domain html request with jquery? Trying to use plug-in

Tags: jquery, html, cross-domain, yql

I'm trying to perform a simple html request using jquery with the code below.

```
$.get('http://externalsite.com/status.html', function(data) {

if (data == 1) {
//do something
}

else {
//do something else
}

});
```

I'm using the cross domain request plugin found at http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/
and I added the .js script to my html file, but what's next?  The example uses a #container and a load from google, but I'm lost as to what I do for an html request.  It says it works for any .get request, I just don't know how to do it.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do whatever you want. Read the jQuery docs for [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) and [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)
:

This example puts the contents of `http://google.com` in the HTML element with `id="container"`:

```
$('#container').load('http://google.com');
```

This does the same thing but with your example site:

```
$('#container').load('http://externalsite.com/status.html');
```

This also does the same thing as above:

```
$.get('http://externalsite.com/status.html', function(data) {    
    $('#container').html(data);
});
```

Comment: Ok so I'm making progress and I'm hoping you can help.  The request is going through, but when I tested but using `alert("working" + data)` the returned data was object Object.  Any suggestions?  I might be doing this completely wrong.

Comment: @Davis Are you fetching JSON?

Comment: here is the answer what to do in order to get displayed everything what is returned: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766795/javascript-write-console-debug-output-to-browser

Comment: surely this is a joke. cross-domain requests cannot be made from javascript PERIOD. the exception is JSONP.

Comment: @trinth He is using the cross-domain request plugin for jQuery which uses YQL (the other exception) as seen here (http://christianheilmann.com/2010/01/10/loading-external-content-with-ajax-using-jquery-and-yql/) to make the request. It is not a joke...

Comment: @trinth It's really just proxying a request through Yahoo's servers: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/fDN7t/ and getting back a JSONP response even if the requested server doesn't support JSONP

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure what your problem exactly is, can you for example wrap this code into the function and simple invoke it ? :) 
like

```
function makeAjaxCall(url){
 $.get(url, function (...)
}

makeAjaxCall('http://google.com');
```

Comment: I just don't know how to form my request to get it to work cross domain with the plug in.  Do I need a yahoo YQL link or will any domain work?