# Cross domain problems with my POST function

Tags: ajax, json, api, rest, cross-domain

I have a MVC rest Web API, that have a method that looks like this:

```
 public HttpResponseMessage PostBook(DtoBooks Book)
        {
            if (Book == null)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Book.Id = Guid.Empty;
            BookManager.Instance.Add(Book);
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, Book);
            return response;
        }
```

Its hosted on different domain with IIS.

When I want to test to do a post I type following js:

```
jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://domain-2:9090/api/Values/",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { CallToActionUrl: 'http://domain-2/', Message: 'Hello World!', OpenInModal: false, Status: 0, TargetUser: 'domain2\admin', TimeStamp: '2014-02-28', Type: 0 },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("success")
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("Fail")
                }
            });
```

When I have navigated to `http://domain-2:8080/` I can run this ajax and it works perfectly!
But when I try to use it on a different domain lets say domain-3, it fails.

I tried CORS, it works on all browsers beside IE9..

Is there any solutions for this? Would appreciate it alot.

Comment: If you are attempting to make cross-origin ajax requests in IE9, you'll need to use `XDomainRequest` instead of `XMLHttpRequest`.  There is a jQuery plug-in that wraps XDR.  You should be aware that there are some notable limitations of XDR.  Another option would be to use a library like this: https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain.

Answer (score 0):

You can Configure Apache to accept Cross-Site.

There are other solutions given on below links.

[Breaking the cross domain barrier](http://www.slideshare.net/SlexAxton/breaking-the-cross-domain-barrier)

[Cross Domain AJAX Request with YQL and jQuery](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-cross-domain-ajax-request-with-yql-and-jquery--net-10225)

[Cross-domain requests with jQuery](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/)

[Simple cross domain html request with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935477/simple-cross-domain-html-request-with-jquery-trying-to-use-plug-in)

[jQuery ajax, get html cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13958642/jquery-ajax-get-html-cross-domain)

[JavaScript: Use a Web Proxy for Cross-Domain XMLHttpRequest Calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13958642/jquery-ajax-get-html-cross-domain)

Hope above links might help.

Comment: Modified the answer and added some links.

Comment: None of them works or are not the same type that Im doing, I am doing a POST and cant use JSONP and using CORS it wont work with IE9.

Answer (score -1):

Does your error message mention something about cross domain policy?
I had a similar problem, and got that message.

try creating a file crossdomain.xml on your webservice folder and including the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<\!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" />
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

You may want to change the * for another more restrictive value. But you may work from there on, if it works

Comment: Your answer only applies to flash.  This question is not about flash.

Comment: @Ray Nicholus I disagree. My answer does not only apply to flash. It also applies, for eg, to Silverlight. It might not apply to Obsivus question, but it may apply to some one else looking for answers. Your remark is inaccurate

Comment: Ok, I take that back - your answer applies only to obsolete technologies that have nothing at all to do with the original question. Better?

Comment: They're obsolete now, and the question was edited after I posted my answer. Still, it may well help someone who still maintains an application with obsolete technology. It does happen... So I'm not going to continue this arguement. be happy